# Outlier in grouped data

Tags: t-test, outliers

Existencial crysis here xD.
When you want to determine outliers with IQR, and plotting a box-plot what do you plot if your data is structure in the following manner:

- n-dependent variables (n=6) (genes)
- j-treatments (j=2) (drugs)
- k-time_points (k=2) (in time)

For a ttest to compare two means: for each time_point and for each dependent variable the mean of treatments are compared. But since the mean difference could be zero, how do you detect the outlier? By grouping for each dependent variable and time_point the two treatments, or keep the treatments separated?

Thank you in advance

tldr: how to group data to test for outliers?

Comment: Why do you want to detect outliers? Understanding that might help people to know what might help you. By the way: What you describe sounds a bit like looking at the residuals from a model that accounts for treatment and time point (and allowing for different variances etc. at each time-point and treatment).

Comment: In fact I am trying to prove that there are no outliers. OK, I will add a tldr

Comment: Why do you want to prove that there are no outliers? I.e. what do you want to justify on that basis?

Comment: An outlier of what? Do you have some response variables and you want to find outliers of that (for all your data, for each group, ...)? Or do you want to find a proband that is an outlier? Or do you want to find a combination of time and treatment that is an outlier (gives very different results compared to the other combinations of time treatment)? **An outlier is always an odd entity in a larger set of entities. So what is your larger set of entities?**

Comment: Figure out, and show that human decisions to remove data point are not always supported by a statistical test

Comment: @frank say I want to compare in one time point the effect of one treatment (one treatment is the control) for each of the 6 genes (response variables). What data should be in the box plot?